# Getting closest li with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, click, removeclass

I try to get with jQuery the closest li on button click and remove it but doesn't seems to fire

**here is my markup**

```
<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="22">
    <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle"></div>
    <div class="dd3-content">some other
        <span class="pull-right" style="display: none;">
            <a data-target="#settings_22" data-action="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        </span>
    </div>

    <form method="post" action="#" class="menu_settings" style="display: block;">
        <input type="hidden" value="22" name="id">
        <fieldset>

            <div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                    <button type="button" data-action="update" class="update btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Update</button>
                    <button type="button" data-action="delete" class="delete btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Trash</button>
                    <button type="button" class="cancel btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>    
                </div>                                
            </div>
        </fieldset>                        
    </form>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('button.update, button.delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = ajaxurl + '?action=updateCategories';
    var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            data: data,
            command:action
        },
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            if (action == 'delete') {
                alert('delete');
                $(this).closest('li').remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I do get the alert but the list is not removed

Comment: it is working :http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/FzN77/

Comment: Working Here - **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJb9c/)**

Comment: I made an update on my hole jquery showing how do I try to use

Comment: here is only one li, in which all your controls, do you want to remove this li or there is some other li(next to this li) which you want to remove.

Comment: In `$(this).closest('li').remove();`, `$(this)` probably isn't referring to what you think it's referring to.

Comment: so I have a list of elements on click I want to remove the closest

Comment: thanks @j08691 for the tipp inbounding $(this) in a variable is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the success callback is executed with `this` referencing `window`; this is probably not what you want.

You can bind `this` in the success callback using the `context` option of `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    context: this,
    ...
});
```

This makes sure using `$(this)` inside the success callback will be the clicked element.